# OpenCV 4.0 Lane Detection

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am working on raspberry Pi self-driving car (College Project). I am using OpenCV 4.0 for identifying lanes in the road (which are yellow). Example:
[image: Lane]

I tried thresholding in HLS Range: `Scalar(20, 120, 80), Scalar(45, 200, 255)` with :[image: HSL Mask]

> Can anyone help with threshold values or any tip for avoiding bright
>   spots. Or any other method for detecting lanes

Comment: can you manually create a mask of all the desired lane pixels and show a HS(L)-histogram? In addition, show such a histogram for the unwanted pixels.

Comment: For fast playing around, increase the minimum saturation, e.g. `(20, 120, 160)`, and decrease the maximum lightness, e.g. `(45, 175, 255)`. With these values, I mainly get the yellow lane in the "foreground".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HSV colorspace works well. The process is the same as HSL.
I used [this python script](https://github.com/twenty-twenty/opencv_basic_color_separator) in the image to get the values.

[image]